# "Pending" in Chrome When Lazy Loading Images in Dynamically Loaded Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, jquery-lazyload

I have a page with multiple independent sections displayed in tabs, each containing potentially hundreds of images. To make page load performant, I am doing two things:

- Loading the sections in parallel with JQuery promises
- Lazy loading the images with a [JQuery lazy load plugin](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload) once those sections are rendered

Here is the pseudocode for how I am doing this in Coffeescript:

```
    $.when.apply($, sectionPromises).then( () ->
      render each section
      $("img.lazyload").lazyload() 
      return
    )
```

What ends up happening is the first few images at the top of the first tabbed section load fine, but all subsequent images--whether lower down in that first section or in other tabbed sections entirely--are simply "(pending)" in Chrome.

This does not happen in other parts of the site where I use the plugin to lazy load images in pages that are constructed conventionally (all at once). But here is the funny thing. The problem *sometimes* doesn't happen if I have Chrome Developer Tools open as I scroll down or move across tabs. Everything loads perfectly. How wild is that?

Any ideas on how to get these lazy loaded images in dynamically generated content to load properly in Chrome--without having Chrome Developer Tools open--is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a self-contained example of the problem? It's probably a bug in the lazy loading plugin that you're using.

Comment: This is actually the second lazy loading plugin I've tried. The same issue happens with [this one](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) too.

Comment: Do you see them as "pending" in the network tab?

Comment: Yes. Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best thing I could find is to navigate to `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` and hit the "Flush socket pools" button at the top of the page. Once I refresh the page with all the images, they all lazily load as they should.

Obviously expecting clients to tweak their browsers, let alone to know how, isn't an option, but for the time being this works.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had a similar problem, but for me it was that the elements were not visible in the same order as the DOM suggested (not sequentially in the DOM), so the Lazyload plugin checks some elements, see that they are not in viewport and stops execution.

You can try to increase the `failure_limit` option to something high, see the [jQuery.lazyload Docs](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/v1/) under "When Images Are Not Sequential":

> By default loop is stopped when first image outside viewport is found. This is based on following assumption. Order of images on page is same as order of images in HTML code. With some layouts assumption this might be wrong. You can control loading behaviour with failure_limit setting.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    failure_limit : 10
});
```

Comment: Good to know, but unfortunately this didn't help me. Thanks for the tip though.